# what does alloc_calls and free_calls mean?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

Can anyone tell me what the output of the following implies,
/sys/kernel/slab/kmalloc-128/alloc_calls
/sys/kernel/slab/kmalloc-128/free_calls

Thanks in advance

Comment: Obviously, these are numbers of allocation and free calls for given memory cache. `kmalloc-128` is a memory cache for memory chunks of size 128 bytes. Allocations with 64 < size <= 128 are redirected to that cache.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev. But my alloc_calls count is increasing and one point of time, it is decreasing...What does that mean?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know.